# xdb replication from Oracle to EDB - table structural change

Tags: oracle, postgresql

If Oracle is master DB in XDB replication (single master), how do you go about structural changes that should be implemented on the Oracle (and EDB) database. I see that if Postgres is master DB, you can use DDL change replication feature on the xdb replication server, but that can't be used if Oracle is the publication DB.

Comment: please clear your question.

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Best I could do:
-   Stop publication/subscription services on XDB replication server
-   On Oracle side
o   Alter original Oracle table (add column)
o   Make copy of shadow table (RRST_...)
o   Drop and recreate shadow table adding new column twice (new and old value)
o   Copy data from temporary shadow table into new shadow table
o   Drop temporary shadow table
o   Change triggers (update and insert triggers, delete trigger is ok) on original Oracle table (RRPI_ and RRPU_ triggers)
-   On Postgres side alter receiving table 
-   Start publication/subscription services on XDB replication server